# How to check if user name exists and match the existing user name UpperCases and LowerCases

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, mysql-real-escape-string

Im using the following code to check if username exists, But this script ignores capital letters.

So **JAMES** is the same as **James**

**Q1**:

How do i ensure that the string matches the existing strings(*UserNames*) in the database as they are and **JAMES** is not equated to **James**.

**Q2**: mysql_real_escape_string

I only want to allow Numbers and Letters, but i want to detect these unwanted CHARS and tell the user that those funny CHARS are not allowed.

Here's my **PHP** Block of Code

```
$l = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['l']);
     if ( $l == ''){
    echo 'Please Enter your desired username.';
} else {
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = '$l'") or die (mysql_error()); 
if (mysql_num_rows($Result) > 0){
     echo '<span style="color:#F00">Sorry this User-Name is already taken, please choose another User-Name</span>';
} else {
    echo '<span style="color:#090">'.$l.' is ok, Please go ahead and fill the form.</span>';
    }
}
```

**NOTES**:
- I'm aware of my deprecated mysql, i'll sort it out soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1 - eh? Dunno why you would want to do this but here you go anyway :-D

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY `uname` = '$l'"
```

That makes your search case sensitive

Q2 - simplest way is to just regex is

```
$newString = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $oldStringWithLoadsOfNaughtyStuff);

if($newString !== $oldStringWithLoadsOfNaughtyStuff){
    //naughty characters must be there as strings do not match.
    echo "naughty Naughty - you have enter illegal characters - only letters and numbers please";

}else{

    //all good here

}
```

Comment: What? do you think allowing the caps to match lower cases is good? Why?

Comment: Well if I join your site as Graaam (my tag normally) then someone else can come as gRaaam - if they are an idiot then they may think I am an idiot to. just an observation - does the code help?

Comment: Cool stuff - if my answer helped mark as accepted answer please - im on a bit of a rep mission (711 rep in 2.5 days - and still not quite number 1 for weekly rankings :-P)

Comment: Undefined variable: oldStringWithLoadsOfNaughtyStuff

Comment: Weekly randings? Where does one see such?

Comment: You will get undefined variable - $l is what you are needing to replace it with

Answer (score 0):

Binary collation can be used:

```
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = '$l' COLLATE utf8_bin;");
```